# Joining two tables that have validity intervals

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables : one with information about products and their selling prices

```
article_id  sell_price_at   validity_start_at      validity_end_at
advFUJKAx   2.99            2023-06-14T10:46:07    2024-02-15T00:59:59
advFUJKAx   2.99            2022-05-11T04:20:13    2023-06-14T10:46:07
advFUJKAx   2.99            2022-05-10T13:23:18    2022-05-11T04:20:13
advFUJKAx   2.99            2022-05-10T13:08:45    2022-05-10T13:23:18
```

And another one about promotions and the values of the promotions. A promotion can change during its lifetime, for instance we decide that it was too much and we change the promotion to something less.

```
article_id  promotion_id    promotion_value promotion_mechanism real_start_datetime real_end_datetime
advFUJKAx                                                       2023-06-27T23:59:59 2024-02-15T00:59:59
advFUJKAx   2GLCMltLyw      1.8             IMMEDIATE_DISCOUNT  2023-06-22T13:31:46 2023-06-27T23:59:59
advFUJKAx   2GLCMltLyw      2.49            IMMEDIATE_DISCOUNT  2023-06-19T08:58:40 2023-06-22T13:31:46
advFUJKAx   2GLCMltLyw      2.49            IMMEDIATE_DISCOUNT  2023-06-16T11:29:38 2023-06-19T08:58:40
advFUJKAx   2GLCMltLyw      2.49            IMMEDIATE_DISCOUNT  2023-06-14T15:05:31 2023-06-16T11:29:38
advFUJKAx                                                       2022-05-18T00:00:00 2023-06-13T00:00:00
advFUJKAx   -38_P0evh       2.29            IMMEDIATE_DISCOUNT  2022-05-11T05:03:04 2022-05-18T00:00:00
advFUJKAx   -38_P0evh       2.49            IMMEDIATE_DISCOUNT  2022-05-11T00:00:00 2022-05-11T05:03:04
advFUJKAx                                                       2022-05-10T13:08:45 2022-05-11T00:00:00
```

As you can see, for the promotions I have already filled the 'holes' in the intervals, meaning that for a given article, the corresponding rows in the promotion table will always share the minimum starting date and the maximum ending date. Also, I have added empty rows in the middle of the promotions table, corresponding to the interval when no promotions where active.

I am trying to join those two tables in order to be able to recreate pricing date intervals, taking into account the promotions so that I can have my `sell_price_at` column, and a new one : `sell_price_at_after_discount`.

I'm just it's very easy, but I can't see to wrap my head around it. I've tried different ways of joining the two tables but nothing seems to work.

I'm working on BigQuery, I don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: Best provide a third table with your ideal output. It helps readers follow your logic more clearly.

Comment: This might be a helpful read https://infinitelambda.com/multitable-scd2-joins/ . But agreed with Clifford, providing the exact expected result would help

Comment: @CliffordPiehl let's say I have a product whose price did not move from the 1st to the 10th. Let's say I have a promotion that was active from the 4th to the 6th. My final table would have 3 rows : one from the 1st to the 4th, with no promotion, one from the 4th to the 6th, with the promotion, and the last one from the 6th to the 10th, without promotion.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your desired outcome of joining the two tables and calculating the `sell_price_at_after_discount` taking into account promotions, you can follow these steps:

- `Join` the two tables on `article_id` and filter based on the overlapping time intervals (**validity_start_at** and **validity_end_at** for `products`, **real_start_datetime** and **real_end_datetime** for `promotions`).
- Use a `CASE` statement to calculate the **sell_price_at_after_discount** considering the promotion values.

```
SELECT
  promo.article_id,
  promo.promotion_value,
  promo.real_start_datetime,
  promo.real_end_datetime,
  CASE
    WHEN promo.promotion_value IS NOT NULL THEN products.sell_price_at - promo.promotion_value
    ELSE products.sell_price_at
  END AS sell_price_at_after_discount
FROM
  `babynames.promotions_table` promo
JOIN (
  SELECT
  article_id,
  sell_price_at,
  validity_start_at,
  validity_end_at
FROM
  `babynames.products_table`
) products
ON
  products.article_id = promo.article_id
AND
  products.validity_start_at <= promo.real_start_datetime
AND
  products.validity_end_at >= promo.real_end_datetime
```

Output:
[image]